# How do I add a radio group to a table cell using iTextSharp 4.1.6?

Tags: itext

I'm trying to generate a dynamic survey as a PDF.  The question text appears in the first cell, and the field appears in the 2nd cell.  I have no problems when adding a text field or drop down field, but I cannot get a radio group to display.  I am able to get a single radio button, but would like the entire group to display in the cell.  Is this possible? And if so, how?

Here is a code sample of what I've tried thus far.

```
Table.AddCell(Question.TEXT + ":");
PdfFormField RadioGroup = PdfFormField.CreateRadioButton(ExportWriter, true);
RadioGroup.FieldName = "field" + Question.QUESTION_ID;
using (Entities _context = new Entities())
{
    QuestionOptions = SURVEY.GetQuestionOptions(Question.QUESTION_ID, _context).ToList();
}
RadioCheckField Radio;
PdfFormField RadioField = null;

foreach (OPTIONS Option in QuestionOptions)
{
    Radio = new RadioCheckField(ExportWriter, new Rectangle(40, 806 - count * 40, 60, 788 - count * 40), Option.OPTION_NAME, "option" + Option.OPTION_ID.ToString());
    Radio.BackgroundColor = new GrayColor(0.8f);
    Radio.CheckType = RadioCheckField.TYPE_CIRCLE;
    RadioField = Radio.RadioField;
    RadioField.SetWidget(new Rectangle(10, 20), PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_INVERT);
    RadioGroup.AddKid(RadioField);
}
ExportWriter.AddAnnotation(RadioGroup);
Cell = new PdfPCell();
Events = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.events.FieldPositioningEvents(ExportWriter, RadioGroup);
Cell.CellEvent = Events;
Table.AddCell(Cell);
```

The issue is that when the radio buttons appear, they appear on the bottom left of the page, and not within the cell.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please note that all versions prior to iTextSharp 5 have been declared End-of-Life a couple of years ago. These versions should no longer be used: http://itextpdf.com/salesfaq As such you should not expect any answers to questions about that obsolete version.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a discontinued version of the software. (Also: there is no code sample of what the OP has tried.)

Comment: I didn't see that the tag was iTextSharp 5, just iTextSharp.  I can update to include a code sample.  It's definitely not off-topic though.

Comment: The problem is that you're using a version of the software that dates from 2009. That's 5 years ago. If you are writing code for a customer, you're selling him outdated software. If he finds out, he will not be pleased.

Comment: This is one heck of a sales pitch.

Comment: I'm an engineer, not a sales guy. My favorite quote is on this year's calendar by Deloitte: http://itextpdf.com/node/423?size=_original **Good engineers build great technology. Great engineers also create a sustainable business model.** Building a solution on top of obsolete software may make sense from the point of view of a *good* engineer, but a *great* engineer will say it's not a sustainable solution... ;-)

Comment: Is what I'm attempting possible with the new version?

Comment: Yes, it's possible with the old and new version, but not with `FieldPositioningEvents`. You'll need to write a custom implementation of the `PdfPCellEvent`.